# Woocommerce. Как можно добавить еще одну переменную в код?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На сайте есть категория товаров "Распродажа". У этих товаров есть обычная цена, к ним нужно добавить sale price по формуле (обычная цена * 1,5).

Как добавить еще одну категорию в данный код?

```
/**
 * Calculate regular price.
 *
 * @param mixed      $price   Price.
 * @param WC_Product $product Product.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function calc_regular_price( $price, $product ) {
    $cat_id  = 5;
    $cat_ids = $product->get_category_ids();

    if ( ! in_array( $cat_id, $cat_ids, true ) ) {
        return $price;
    }

    return $price * 1.5;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'calc_regular_price', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Calculate sale price.
 *
 * @param mixed      $price   Price.
 * @param WC_Product $product Product.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function calc_sale_price( $price, $product ) {
    $cat_id  = 5;
    $cat_ids = $product->get_category_ids();

    if ( ! in_array( $cat_id, $cat_ids, true ) ) {
        return $price;
    }

    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'calc_sale_price', 10, 2 );
    $price = $product->get_regular_price();
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'calc_sale_price', 10, 2 );

    return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'calc_sale_price', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: А если $cat_id = array(5,6,7);

Comment: Распродажа (скидка) - родная функция WC. Зачем костыли?

Comment: @eugene_vandar Вот почему то не работает так и var_dump() ничего не показывает. С одной все нормально.

Comment: @SeVlad не моя прихоть ;) Ну и тем более эта цена нужна скорее для видимости скидки т.к. по сути ничего не меняется.

Comment: @SeVlad наверное потому что человеку лень обновлять цены и ему проще, чтоб цена умножалась на коэф. и показывала псевдо-старую цену. Немного глупо, но человек себе так придумал

Comment: @eugene_vandar для этого не нужна отдельная категория товаров. Это не только плодить и смешивать сущности, но и гемморой в работе .Для "работы" же "по к/ф" есть 100500 готовых, проверенных  решений. Особенно если помнить что меняться может не только цена, но и сами эти к/ф

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Меняете `$cat_id` на массив. Затем с помощью `array_intersect` ищите пересечения массивов:

```
...
$sale_cat_ids = [ 5, 10 ];
$cat_ids      = $product->get_category_ids();

if ( ! array_intersect( $sale_cat_ids, $cat_ids ) ) {
    return $price;
}
...
```

Comment: большое спасибо!